# Multiprocessing: Passing a class instance to pool.map

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing

I swear I saw the following in an example somewhere, but now I can't find that example and this isn't working. <strike>The __call__ class function never gets called.</strike>

**EDIT: Code updated**

pool.map appears to start the QueueWriter instance and the __call__ function is reached. However, the workers never seem to start or at least no results are pulled from the queue. Is my queue set up the right way? Why do the workers not fire off?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import random

class QueueWriter(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        self.grid = kwargs.get("grid")
        self.path = kwargs.get("path")

    def __call__(self, q):
        print self.path
        log = open(self.path, "a", 1)
        log.write("QueueWriter called.\n")    
        while 1:
            res = q.get()
            if res == 'kill':
                self.log.write("QueueWriter received 'kill' message. Closing Writer.\n")
                break
            else:
                self.log.write("This is where I'd write: {0} to grid file.\n".format(res))

        log.close()
        log = None

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.queue = kwargs.get("queue")
        self.grid = kwargs.get("grid")

    def __call__(self, idx):
        res = self.workhorse(self, idx)
        self.queue.put((idx,res))
        return res

    def workhorse(self,idx):
        #in reality a fairly complex operation
        return self.grid[idx] ** self.grid[idx]


if __name__ == '__main__':
#     log = open(os.path.expanduser('~/minimal.log'), 'w',1)
    path = os.path.expanduser('~/minimal.log')

    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    manager = mp.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()

    grid = [random.random() for _ in xrange(10000)] 
    # in actuality grid is a shared resource, read by Workers and written
    # to by QueueWriter

    qWriter = QueueWriter(grid=grid, path=path)
    watcher = pool.map(qWriter, (q,),1)
    wrkr = Worker(queue=q,grid=grid)
    result = pool.map(wrkr, range(10000), 1)
    result.get()
    q.put('kill')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

So the log does indeed print the initialization message, but then __call__ function is never called. Is this one of those pickling issues I've seen discussed so often? I've found answers about class member functions, but what about class instances?

Comment: Suggest you read [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and create one for your problem.

Comment: Processes don't share objects, each pool worker gets a copy of the instance. Take a look at this for more info about communication between processes https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes.

Comment: Sorry Rico, I don't understand. I already assumed they were getting a copy of the instance. Why does that prevent the \__call__ method from being called?

Comment: That's much closer to a MCVE, although I changed the definition of `grid` to `grid = [random.random() for _ in xrange(10000)]` since I don't have numpy installed. However after doing that, I get a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` for the `watcher = pool.map(qWriter, (q,), 1)` line — which I don't think is related to my modification, but am unsure to what file the message refers.

Comment: Kris: Are the results I got — a `ValueError` because of a closed file — the same as you're getting? You don't really say what does happen, only what doesn't (the class's `__call__` method isn't being called).

Comment: @martineau The problem with the minimal example was where the log file was being called. If it is called in the main function (or even the init function, it seems) it will not be open in the child process. I moved it into the `__call__` function. Now the QueueWriter instance starts, but the workers do not. Sorry if I've been unclear, but I'm not sure what specific question to ask really.

Comment: Kris: Your latest code never gets past the `watcher = pool.map(qWriter, (q,),1)` statement because the `map` call blocks until the callable —  `qWriter.__call__()` — returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the gentle and patient prodding of [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) (thanks!) I think I've ironed out the problems. I have yet to apply it to my original code, but it is working in the example above and I'll start new questions for future implementation problems.

So in addition to changing where in the code the target file (the log, in this example) gets opened, I also started the QueueWriter instance as a single multiprocessing process rather than using `pool.map`. As [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) pointed out the map call blocks until the `qWriter.__call__()` returns and this prevented the workers from being called.

There were some other bugs in the code above, but those were incidental and fixed below:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import random

class QueueWriter(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        self.grid = kwargs.get("grid")
        self.path = kwargs.get("path")

    def __call__(self, q):
        print self.path
        log = open(self.path, "a", 1)
        log.write("QueueWriter called.\n")    
        while 1:
            res = q.get()
            if res == 'kill':
                log.write("QueueWriter received 'kill' message. Closing Writer.\n")
                break
            else:
                log.write("This is where I'd write: {0} to grid file.\n".format(res))

        log.close()
        log = None

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.queue = kwargs.get("queue")
        self.grid = kwargs.get("grid")

    def __call__(self, idx):
        res = self.workhorse(idx)
        self.queue.put((idx,res))
        return res

    def workhorse(self,idx):
        #in reality a fairly complex operation
        return self.grid[idx] ** self.grid[idx]


if __name__ == '__main__':
#     log = open(os.path.expanduser('~/minimal.log'), 'w',1)
    path = os.path.expanduser('~/minimal.log')

    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    manager = mp.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()

    grid = [random.random() for _ in xrange(10000)] 
    # in actuality grid is a shared resource, read by Workers and written
    # to by QueueWriter

    qWriter = QueueWriter(grid=grid, path=path)
#     watcher = pool.map(qWriter, (q,),1)
# Start the writer as a single process rather than a pool
    p = mp.Process(target=qWriter, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    wrkr = Worker(queue=q,grid=grid)
    result = pool.map(wrkr, range(10000), 1)
#     result.get()
# not required for pool
    q.put('kill')
    pool.close()
    p.join()
    pool.join()
```